# My out put doesn't match the one i need how can I fix this?

Tags: python

I have to write a program in python that prints out a pascal's triangle with ten rows, this is what I have so far

```
def combination(n, k):

    if k == 0 or k == n:
        return (str(1))
    else:
        return ( str ((n-1)+(n-1)) )

def pascals_triangle(rows):
    
   for row in range(rows):
        answer = ""
        for column in range(row + 1):
            answer = answer + combination(row, column) + "\t"
        print(answer)

pascals_triangle(10)
```

the out put I get is

1
1   1
1   2   1
1   4   4   1
1   6   6   6   1
1   8   8   8   8   1
1   10  10  10  10  10  1
1   12  12  12  12  12  12  1
1   14  14  14  14  14  14  14  1
1   16  16  16  16  16  16  16  16  1

but the out put I need is

1
1   1
1   2   1
1   3   3   1
1   4   6   4   1
1   5   10  10  5   1
1   6   15  20  15  6   1
1   7   21  35  35  21  7   1
1   8   28  56  70  56  28  8   1
1   9   36  84  126 126 84  36  9   1

How can I fix this

Comment: Your code does what you specified, you just specified it wrongly. Consider going through your code step by step. You will notice that if row == 3, `combination(4, 2)` must return 4. (3-1)+(3-1). Think about how you can solve this, perhaps by looking at the definition of [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Formula).

Answer (score 0):

```py
def pascals_triangle(rows):
    if rows == 1:
        print(1)
        return [1]

    prev = pascals_triangle(rows-1)

    curr_row = [1] + [x+y for x, y in zip(prev[:-1], prev[1:])] + [1]

    for el in curr_row:
        print(el, ' ', end='')
    print()

    return curr_row

pascals_triangle(10)
```